# Is there any kind of theme on WordPress to sell my own movies?

Tags: plugins, plugin-development, themes

Hope you all are doing well. Sorry if it is non-related topic in this website, but I was struggling to find an answer for my question. I would like to create a website on WordPress where I could put my movies and sell them. There are plenty number of themes, but they don't work with WooCommerce (in a sense you need to create both movie and product pages which is time consuming). I would like to find a theme where admin could create a movie and put the price for it in the same page.  Is there any kind of theme that works in that way? I appreciate your help. Thank you.

Comment: Many ways to do this, one would be a memership level plugin... ie. create a paid membership level for each movie. Then a page with each movie embed and restrict access to the content to the corresponding membership level. This way users can login and rewatch the movie they've purchased.

Comment: Yes, but number of clicks for every operation will be much time consuming, no?

Comment: Don't see much difference really. Whether it is setup as a product or a memberhips product, the sales process would be almost exactly the same.

Comment: Thank you for your comment, but maybe you didn't get the point. If I give the product to the customer, he/she has to do so many operations which is bad. What I want to do is just add movie and product pages at the same time.

Comment: yes the admin process on adding records and the sales process to the customer are indeed very different things. sorry I'm not sure now which one you are wanting to solve most.

Comment: So, just imagine a website with lots of local movies and you want to sell each of them  as single product and after user buys that product/movie he/she can watch/stream the movie in the website. The thing is that I want to restrict the movie to each user that they bought.